# I have a layout that contains relative layout with two vertical linear layouts that displays on a zebra MC67

Tags: android-layout

But the same activity blows up loading on a zebra m6000. Let me state that I am a novice using Android Studio and Java. I have been a VB programmer for many years. 
The XML has 2 includes. One foe each vertical linear layout. I can add the XML's for them if needed.
What could cause the rendering to work on one android device (which is running an earlier version of OS ) but fail on newer device.

Here is XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGray"
    tools:context="com.procatdt.stockright.activities.PutAwayAreaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

       >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/frm1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/layout_numpad5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
           />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you are getting and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to add picture. can find option to insert or upload photo

Comment: added picture as answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is how it is rendering on MC67

Answer (score 0):

Found Issue. One of the Buttons in my include was the culprit. KitKat didn't care but lollipop didn't like the backgroundtint value.
Looking through logcat I saw culprit was a button and from there it was process of elimination.